# How to get items of generic type from ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I thought this will be a trivial task, but all is not that simple. The thing is that a user can insert item(s) into `ComboBox` in two ways:

1. By simply typing in a text
2. By pasting data from clipboard (by means of a button).

First, I had this extension method:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(this ComboBox comboBox)
{
    return comboBox.Items.Cast<T>();
}
```

And usage:

```
var items = comboBox.GetItems<string>();
```

This *does not* work for manually typed text, since this text doesn't belong to `Items` collection - and thus I get empty list. One trick I thought of is to insert this text into `Items` collection before returning:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(this ComboBox comboBox)
{
    if (!comboBox.HasItems)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Add(comboBox.Text);
    }
    return comboBox.Items.Cast<T>();
}
```

But then we have a problem here: a user can type another text, and then we have *two* items, because previous text was inserted! We can clear `Items` collections before proceeding, but... what if items were inserted through clipboard? :) This way all items pasted will be cleared out? :)
Do I miss something? Is there some solution to it?

Comment: Sounds too complex logic to handle with a premade combobox, create custom control and template how ever you want it.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Can I see an example of how to do it? Remember that in first case I have clear text - I can't cast it into `T` type!

Answer (score 0):

Fix `combobox1.Items.Add()` function. Change `combobox1.Items.Add(combobox.Text);` to `combobox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(){Content=combobox1.Text});`

That's all you have to do.